# Angular / Javascript - Re-Organizar posições no Array

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

```
let meuArray = [
   {codigo: 1, nome: Jose,   idade: 33}
   ,{codigo: 2,  nome: Jose,     idade: 32}
   ,{codigo: 3,  nome: Maria,    idade: 31}
   ,{codigo: 4,  nome: Joao,     idade: 30}
   ,{codigo: 5,  nome: Aroldo,   idade: 29}
   ,{codigo: 6,  nome: Aristide, idade: 28}
   ,{codigo: 7,  nome: Aline,    idade: 27}
   ,{codigo: 8,  nome: Amelia,   idade: 26}
   ,{codigo: 9,  nome: Milena,   idade: 25}
   ,{codigo: 10, nome: Andrea,   idade: 24}
]
```

Tenho esse array de objetos (Obvio que num exemplo real, são minimo de 10.000 registros). Gostaria reorganizar não as linhas do array, mais os atributos dos objetos. Tipo: Colocar Idade como Primeiro, Codigo como ultimo. Ex: {idade: 24, nome: Andrea, codigo: 10}.

Alguma ideia? das formas tradicionais (Utilizando o for), fica muito, mais muito lento.

Comment: Porque ?????????????? isso não tem efeito nenhum, qual é a razão ?

Comment: Como assim? Reorganizar as propriedades? Isso não faz o mínimo sentido!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var texto = [{'codigo': 1, 'nome':'maria', 'idade':20},
             {'codigo': 2, 'nome':'joao', 'idade':20}];
var pessoas = this.texto.map(function (key){
    return {idade: key.idade, nome: key.nome, codigo: key.codigo };
    });
```

Lembrando que  você não precisa reorganizar os atributos do objeto para jogar na tabela ou onde quiser com ng-for, "ngFor", ou qualquer outra forma de bind no AngularJS e Angular;

*.component.html

```
 <div id="tabela">
    <h2>Bind Com Angular</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
             <th>Idade</th>
             <th>Nome</th>
             <th>codigo</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let txt of texto" >
          <td>{{txt.idade}}</td>
          <td>{{txt.nome}}</td>
          <td>{{txt.codigo}}</td>    
        </tr>             
    </table>    
</div>
```

Pronto, no Angular o bind é feito dessa forma, existe outras. Se tiver 10.000 registro Json, vai criar a tabela com os 10.000.

Comment: Mais é exatamente pra isso que preciso! Quero trocar as posições das colunas de uma tabela property bind! Como faria isso?

Comment: @LuizFelipe espero ter ajudado!

Comment: O property bind eu consigo fazer! era reorganizar as colunas. valeu